# chrome extension: how to make browser action on/off javascript injection on ever page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Basically when you hit the browser action, it will activate "ON" mode, it will inject javascript on every new page the person navigates to including new tab. When it's "OFF", it should no longer inject javascript on new page.

Current solution will only execute the javascript when you turn it on and will require clicking on over and over on new page load.

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"SCRIPT.user.js"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"alert()"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the state in localStorage or variable, and execute the script every time the page refreshed.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(tab){
    if (toggle)
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({tab.is,code:{'alert()'})
})
```

I also recommend you to use localStorage (or chrome storage api, to store the toggle var, after chrome restart)

Comment: is there a way to do this without localStorage?

Comment: The example I showed you it is without localStorage

Comment: i added this too background.js but it doesn't appear.

Comment: the code above actually has syntax errors. also chrome.tabs don't have that listener event.

Comment: Edited. It's webNavigation, no tabs.